# Setting Focus on next item becoming visible while leaving ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, textbox, focus

I have a `ComboBox` with `AutoCompleteMode` set to `Suggest`. The next control in sequence is a `TextBox`. Depending on the selected item of the `ComboBox` the `TextBox` is `visible` or not `visible`. Furthermore there another text shouldn't be entered which isn't contained in the elements of the list of the `ComboBox`. So at leaving of the `ComboBox` I Check the value at `Validating`.

```
private void cb_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
  if(cb.SelectedValue == null)
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
  }
  tb.Visible = cb.Text.Contains("XX"); // makes TextBox visible/invisible
}
```

Now there is the problem if the `TextBox` is invisible and a user types in the `ComboBox` some letters and goes with key down to an item which makes the `TextBox` visible and press the tabulator key then the focus skips the following text box which becomes visible. How to achive that the text box will not be skipped in this case?

Comment: Create a variable that contains the index number of the row in the combobox.  Then when you enter the combox select the index number (row).

Comment: I fear you didn't understand the problem. It's at leaving the ComboBox, not at entering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the [Validated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validated?view=netframework-4.8) event to show and select the `TextBox` if the condition is met. Otherwise, hide it and call the [`SelectNextControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) method to select the next control in the tab order.

```cs
private void cb_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = cb.SelectedItem == null;            
}

private void cb_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tb.Visible = cb.Text.Contains("some text");
    if (tb.Visible) tb.Select();
    else SelectNextControl(cb, true, true, true, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
        private void cb_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
            if (cb.SelectedValue == null)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            tb.Visible = cb.Text.Contains("XX"); // makes TextBox visible/invisible
            int index = cb.SelectedIndex;
            cb.SelectedIndex = index + 1;
        }
```